# Azure Powershell to get Host Performance counters?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Is it possible to get Azure Host Performance counters (CPU %, Disk Op/s, Disk B and Net) using powershell cmdlets from all vms inside a subscription?
I can't find any way to do so but Im tired of collecting the info manually from 116 VMs...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest Log Analytics (OMS) for the job instead. It collects performance counters from all VMs automatically and there's little work to do to put together some nice dashboards or use the data as you please.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-performance-counters

If you still want to use PowerShell, create a runbook script in Azure Automation to loop over all VMs, connect to a remote PSSession and execute your collect script while you offload the data to a blob storage.

Comment: The thing is OMS has just been installed but I want to collect previous data, and I also want to export it to a CSV.